# REST API apex - send and receive within a same class

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, force.com-sites

I'm wondering,
Is there an option to receive data with @HTTPGET --> Make some manipulation on this data --> Create new REST request and send it to different URL - On the same Class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `@HttpPost` or `@HttpGet` method can manipulate what it receives and then make an [Http request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) to a different URL.

If you are asking can that different URL be handled by the same class, that depends on the `@RestResource`. If that pattern is fixed like this then no:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/abc/def')
```

but if it includes wildcards then yes, though you will need to add code to explicitly handle the various values:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/abc/*')
```

(There is a hacky approach for a fixed URL in that you can write one Apex method for each of the HTTP methods `@HttpDelete`, `@HttpGet`, `@HttpPatch`, `@HttpPost`, `@HttpPut`. But that is likely to result in a design that is quite different from the normal [REST patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).)